# Python ping script always failed on 1st attempt

Tags: python, linux, networking, device, ping

I'm facing failure issue when run python script to ping nodes in my network and it always fail on my 1st attempt ...when run again...it works. My environment is linux machine and I ping to only 3 devices.

To test it I just create simple script. For 1st attempt it will failed and if i run the script again and again...everything ok... then after i left for 15mins-30mins... I run and it will failed...then run again...ok... May I know if you guyz facing this kind of issue.

The code as follows;

```
def verify_ping():
    ipadd = "192.168.1.1"
    response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + ipadd)

    if response == 0:
        ipstatus = "UP"
    else:
        ipstatus = "DOWN"

    return ipstatus

ping_status = verify_ping()
```

The PING failure a follows

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.1 icmp_seq=1 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.1.100)

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Ping OK

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=250 time=1.33 ms

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
```

At the same time I do continues ping to the IP and so far the IP up and reachable. Maybe someone face the issue or maybe something that i need to add to the script. Please advise further and thank you for your time.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/753034/first-ping-to-any-destination-fails-from-switch-but-not-from-router) is relevant?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is related to a network or OS issue and not to the provided code.

Comment: Thank you sir, I believed the devices ip/mac is already discovered and known and in the mac table...

Comment: Thanks...this related to the code also...as I may did wrong or maybe need to enhance the code for better executn. Just to know if anyone else have face the same behavior. Anyway...thanks

Answer (score 1):

It may be related to an ARP issue. It may depends on the network architecture of your environment, and parameters of your network devices

(see https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/85577)

Comment: But when I ping again to the same ip after 15-30min...it will fail... as what i understand as long the device active in the network it will keep the arp table info of devices that it has been discovered...and will keep the table until the device shutdown or network down. Thanks...this i on networking... to me...i just curious if the script above nothing to do with the issue im facing now... i think probably the issue is on my environment ... thank you sir